# How can I manually change DSR/CTS signals?

Tags: serial-port

I am using WinAPI to tinker with RS232 ports. Using `SetCommState` function I've set `fRtsControl: RTS_CONTROL_HANDSHAKE` and `fDtrControl: DTR_CONTROL_HANDSHAKE`, so from my understanding both DTR/RTS handshakes are now enabled, and now additionaly I need to set `fOutxDsrFlow` and `fOutxCtsFlow` to true, to make this flow work, right?

Having it all set up how can I manually change DSR/CTS to high/low, so I can see what happens?
Or perhaps are RTS/DTR handshakes and DSR/CTS signals completely separate things and I am understanding it incorrectly?

Comment: Those signals are inputs to your machine, driven by the device.  So you're on the wrong end of the wire to change them.

Comment: ok, I understand it now, so the only thing I can affect are DTR/RTS via fDtrControl and fRtsControl properties on dcb, correct?

Answer (score 0):

The DSR/CTS signal has only a passive function of acquiring the state or notifying the change as an event.

If you want to actively control it, you need to prepare another hardware or software for it and use another interface independent of the target serial port.

It's relatively easy to have two virtual COM port device drivers with loopback or port-to-port connectivity.

For example, in the case of software, there is something like this.
[Connecting to serial port (com port) over network](https://gist.github.com/DraTeots/e0c669608466470baa6c)

The same thing is to prepare two USB serial port dongles in terms of hardware and connect them with a cable that crosses DTR/DSR and RTS/CTS.

Both need to be programmed to test the target port/software and run on the opposing port.